# Помогите разобраться с роутингом и компонентами

Tags: javascript, golang, vue.js

Здравствуйте. 
Не могу понять как правильно пользоваться компонентами и роутингом. 
Хочу использовать роутинг от `vuejs`, моя логика такова, что при переходе например на `"/main"`, vuejs будет подгружать родительский компонент в `id="content"`. будет содержать локальные компоненты со своими шаблонами. 
Не совсем понимаю как это правильно сделать. 
Перечитывал документацию несколько раз, но все равно, не смог понять:с

HTML:

```
<div class="center-n" id="content"> 
<main-pg> 
</main-pg> 
</div>
```

VUEJS:

```
var live = Vue.component('main-pg', { 
template: '#live' 
}); 

new Vue({ 
el: '#content', 
})
```

и все, застопорился. 
Пожалуйста, объясните кому не сложно:3 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Что именно вам не понятно?

Все отлично описано здесь: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html (или на русском https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/routing.html)